# Hibernate exception position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want to perform mysql insert query using hibernate, I have this:

```
String q1="INSERT INTO sample (DatasetStatusID,Message,ProcessTime) VALUES('?','?','?') ";
Query query=session.createSQLQuery(q1);
query.setParameter(0, 5);
query.setParameter(1, "TESTING");
query.setParameter(2, new Date());  
int result=query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
```

I have following exception occured,

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryParameterException:
>   Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that
>   ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why do not use `hibernate save()` method instead of `native sql`?

Comment: I am new to hibernate, i know only mysql query

Comment: Did you map your pojos with database table?

Comment: yes i mapped pojo class for table

Comment: Ok,I will add answer how you can save with `hibernate`.

Comment: Ok, i will check table part

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `HIBERNATE` recommended way to save data is `save()`. `HIBERNATE` has all methods for database operations.But some reasons you can use `native sql` query.Saving with `hibernate` look like following:

```
 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     sess.save(YourPojo);
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Recommended Hibernate tutorials:
[Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/index.html)
 [Hibernate Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/)

Comment: Recommended Hibernate tutorials:https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/index.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes surrounding the parameter placeholders (question marks) in the query.

Comment: I also checked parameters 1, 2, 3 ordering same exception occured,   Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the question marks; does that work?

Comment: I checked given format but exception occur, **String q1="INSERT INTO datasethistory(DatasetStatusID,Message,ProcessTime) VALUES(5,'Testing',"+new Date()+") ";**   No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: Is that using numbers 1,2,3, or 0,1,2?  Did you try both?  I looked at some examples and they all call `setParameter(0, ...)` so I was wrong about the parameter numbering.

Comment: I tried both parameter type, i will check if any problem in table part